# Creating a symlink or alias that point to current user´s home sub-folder

Tags: bash, terminal, symbolic-link, alias, ln

Is it possible to create, using terminal on a mac, for a mac, a symlink or an alias to ANY currently logged in user of a mac?

This symlink/alias is to be included as a *"drop destination"* for a folder in a software package.

There are a few issues explaining how to make absolute vs relative symlinks, but this has to take into account that it is to be ANY system´s currently logged in user. And only be a symlink or an alias file, not an installer. That´s a bigger thing.

Here is my current best attempts:

symlink with `ln -s` and relative link, works well, but lacks the **user account** wild-card:

```
cd Desktop/any-folder/

ln -s "../symlinks" symlink-file
```

That one references a directory, "symlinks", in ../ (Desktop/), also on Desktop. Works if the relational structure is intact. I know that I need only remove the "" marks to make it a absolute link path.

But my attempt to create a omni-functional user folder link is not working:

```
ln -s "~/Desktop/symlinks" symlink-file
```

That´s the one I need to solve, if possible. Other libraries or ways are also welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A symlink is to an actual unique location, so you can't have a symlink pointing to a user-dependent location.

Note that "~" is not a wildcard, it is more like a shell typing shortcut(*) that the shell immediately replaces by $HOME. Try

```
bash -c 'echo $1' foo ~/bar
```

and you will see that what you get in $1 is `/home/yourid/bar` (or some OSX equivalent) and not `~/bar`.

You could have more luck with OSX aliases, but I doubt it, this kind of feature looks like a disaster waiting to happen.

(*) See [tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html#Tilde-Expansion) in the Bash reference manual

Comment: Okay, that´s the answer I was afraid of. So in your own account it works, but delivering to another person´s system is not going to work. Adding a shell script will work, but would require an actual installer. **My solution is instead an Automator .app**, a **droplet** for dropping the files on that first checks the user´s home folder and adds a path, then copies the files. That works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @andiOak I'd really like to know what script you used in automator to create this droplet!

Answer (score 0):

"~" is expanded to your home directory only of its is "bare", ie `ls ~` lists your home but `ls "~"` will try to list a '~' file/directory. In a script you should use `$HOME` instead:

```
ln -s "$HOME/Desktop/symlinks" symlink-file
```

Comment: Thanks, and for my own system that works great. But in my VMware os with OSX on it does not work at all. The $HOME is ***my*** home, not ***any*** user´s home folder. How do I do that?

Comment: An alias from where to where? And create by which id? You initial question is not very clear. Should there be a directpry with links to every user's home?In any case if your run in some admin/root id to create links to users you have to find a way to enumerate these users home dirs. On Linux that would be enumerating the subdirectories of `/home/` or processing the contents of `/etc/passwd`. And remember that the id that creates the link owns it, so you may have to chown/chmod the link.

Comment: I see. So there is no "wildcard" character or add-on to `ln` that automatically finds the current user on ***any system*** that uses the intended alias then? The alias/symlink is to be included in a .dmg file for easy installation into any user´s account on any computer running macos. When a user **drops my application files** *onto* the symlink or alias, the files are **copied** to the correct location. 
  

**Example:**
1. a user opens a dmg, downloaded from the web.
2. he/she drags an application folder onto a symlink/alias that then copies it to his/her user-folder/sub-folder.

Comment: EDIT of previous comment, first sentence: _*_ I see. So there is no "wildcard" character that is the equivalent of "the current user name"? _*_